# nginx regex locations with different roots not working as expected

Tags: nginx

I have the following two rules:

```
location / {
    root /var/www/default;
}

location ~* /myapp(.*)$ {
    root /home/me/myapp/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /handle.php?url=$uri&$args;
}
```

When I browse to `myapp/foo` it works- kind of, the error is logged as a 404: `*3 open() "/var/www/default/handle.php" failed (2: No such file or directory)` - so its handling the regex match but just not using the right document root-- why is this?

For the record, I am trying to get /myapp/* requests handled by the second location, and everything else the first.

Comment: Why are you using that regex? `location /myapp/` should be sufficient.

Comment: Replacing the regex with `location /myapp/` still looks in the wrong document root, though (looking for the file `handle.php` in `/var/www/default`

Comment: That's because `/handle.php` isn't in the `/myapp` directory.

Comment: Yes, it is. handle.php is in `/home/me/myap/www` but nginx is trying to serve it out of `/var/www/default` even though the URL is '/myapp/foo` and the location seems to be set up properly.

Comment: You specified `/handle.php` and not `/myapp/handle.php`!

Comment: Ah shoot, I thought doing `/handle.php` would look for it relative to the location's specified root, which it does not. Doing `/myapp/handle.php` does indeed work - thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The working solution should be like this

```
location /myapp/ {
    root /home/me/myapp/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /myapp/handle.php?url=$uri&$args;
}
```

I replacing regex with `/myapp/` because the both configurations should do the job correctly. Then I replace `/handle.php` to `/myapp/handle.php` because the absolute path of `try_files` fallback should be `http://example.com/myapp/handle.php`